# How can I make a count table for demographic information from a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I want to create a table that can be formatted in R summarising demographic data by counts. For example, I have a data frame (example below) that has info on gender, sexuality, and disability. I want a table that shows how many people identify as male, female, heterosexual, homosexual, etc. So basically I want the equivalent of the table(df$gender) function but with multiple variables in one table. And ideally be able to format it to look nice and then exported.

Code here to create a reproducible data frame (although in my real df I have extra columns that I don't want to be included in the table):

```
gender <- c('female','male','male','female','male')
sexuality <- c('heterosexual','bisexual','heterosexual','asexual','homosexual')
disabled <- c('no','no','yes','no','yes')
fake.data <- data.frame(gender,sexuality,disabled)
```

I want a table that looks like this:

```
**Gender**       
Male: 3      
Female: 2

**Sexuality** 
Heterosexual: 2
etc etc
```

How can I do this, please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can call `table` on each column :

```
sapply(fake.data, table)

#$gender

#female   male 
#     2      3 

#$sexuality

#     asexual     bisexual heterosexual   homosexual 
#           1            1            2            1 

#$disabled

# no yes 
#  3   2
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to turn that into a table/dataframe that can be formatted, please?

Comment: @danibradford Would something like `stack(unlist(sapply(fake.data, table)))` work? There is also `data.frame(sapply(fake.data, table))` but I think option with `stack` is better.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work, which might be because in my real data frame there are differing number of rows?

Comment: Does it give any error message? What does it return when you try that?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the level of complexity you want to have for your tables, you can use `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(
  x = fake.data$sexuality[fake.data$disabled=="no"],
  by = list(fake.data$gender[fake.data$disabled=="no"]),
  function(x) table(x))
#  Group.1 x.asexual x.bisexual x.heterosexual x.homosexual
#1  female         1          0              1            0
#2    male         0          1              0            0
```

or:

```
aggregate(
  x = fake.data$sexuality[fake.data$disabled=="yes"],
  by = list(fake.data$gender[fake.data$disabled=="yes"]),
  function(x) table(x)) 
#  Group.1 x.asexual x.bisexual x.heterosexual x.homosexual
#1    male         0          0              1            1
```